# Convert coloured images in a folder to grayscale and store it in a different folder using opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

can anyone help me in converting coloured images in a folder to grayscale and store it in a different folder using opencv

I am expecting a code

Thanks

Comment: Why bother writing OpenCV code? Just use **ImageMagick** at the command line `mkdir results; mogrify -path results -colorspace gray *.png`

Answer (score 2):

You must realize that no one on stackoverflow will write code for you. Here's pseudo/short code for you to do this in Python

```
import os
import cv2
color_imgs = [x for x in os.listdir(color_img_dir) if x[-3:]=='jpg']
for img in color_imgs:
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite(new_path + img_name, gray_img)
```